# mysql -h slow ?? how I can correct this?

Tags: server, mysql

I have 3 server .1 database server(mysql as database) and 2 normal server called A and B.

from A when I try to connect database using the bellow command,the connection is set within a second

```
mysql -h database_server_ip   -u username -p
```

but when I try to connect using B server using same command, it takes around 20-30 second to connect.

Can any one suggest ,How I can correct this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your MySQL configuration file

```
skip-name-resolve
```

For Windows:
my.ini(Mysql installation location )

For Linux:
my.cnf(/etc/my.cnf)

The ‘[mysqld]‘ section of the my.cnf file now looks like this after the changes:

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-locking
skip-name-resolve
```

Now restart the mysql service and you can find some improvement in the performance for remote mysql server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In which machine I should make the change ??in database server or B machine??

Comment: The changes should be made in the database server.